# Why FB.login doesn't ask me for permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I try to publish something with the following code:

```
FB.login(function(response) 
{
   if (response.authResponse) 
   {
      FB.api('/me/feed','post',{
               name: "Nombre",
               link: "http://radio/player/bbc_world_service",
               description: "This is test",
               message : "xxxxxxxx"
            },function(response) {
                  //
      });
   }
   else 
   {
         //
   }
},{scope: 'publish_actions','user_likes'});
```

It doesn't ask me for any permissions, just publishes in my timelime directly. As far as i know theoretically it must ask me for permissions. But i try to do the same thing through facebook explorer, it does ask for.

Answer (score 1):

> It doesn't ask me for any permissions, just publishes in my timelime directly.

This simply means that you've already authorized your app once. Once authorized, it doesn't ask for the permissions again unless new permissions are added.

Delete the app from your Facebook profile and then try again. It will definitely ask for the permissions then.